# Primefaces graphicimage is not working in browser

Tags: image, jsf, browser, primefaces

I want to display an image in the webpage.
I added the following code to the webpage:

```
<h:graphicImage 
   value="D:\\ShopCart\\WebContent\\resources\\images\\WNewClothing\3.png"/>
```

When i run it in the eclipse browser i could see the image, but when i run it on the mozilla , the image was not being displayed. Why is it so? 
Can somebody provide me a solution to this problem? 
I also changed the '`value`'to '`name`', but the problem remains same.

Comment: You have incorrectly assumed that mentioning the full disk file system path would serve images/resources stored in that location. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11988418/1391249) for the way how is accomplished in JSF way. (Do not rely upon non-standard, "eclipse browser", by the way).

Comment: I think you forgot a \  before the 3.png